# Smartphones: How to detect a user leaving the browser?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, smartphone

I'm building a very simple website with a form on it. The user will access it from a smartphone with the standard browser.

He will then put information in the form (a textarea).... BUT he can leave at any time the browser to answer calls, open another app, etc and come back later to finish his note.

Q- Is there a way to detect when the user leave the browser app (quitting, closing, switching, etc) and run a javacript that would in this case SAVE the content so that when he come back (even if he quits the browser), the note will still be there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just a hint, have tried window.onunload or window.onbeforeunload = send some unsynced request to the server ?